# How to set response content type in jboss 5.x ? Is there any configuration setting for jboss 5.x?

Tags: jboss5.x

I need to set response content type to "text/html;charset=UTF-8" at server level in jboss 5.x . Please me help on this topic.

Thanks 
Tahir.

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit the server.xml which is inside jbossweb.sar. Hope the below link would be useful to you

https://community.jboss.org/message/702917

Comment: Please mark the answer as "Right answer" if you find it right. Thanks :)